# password displayed on loggin screen but not on purpose

Tags: shortcut-keys, password, logging

I'm under ubuntu 18.04.1 and I face this issue:
sometimes, not always, when I loggin back, my password is displayed.
I wonder why this happens.

I know that this "password revealation feature" is enabled only when I type my password.
I find this quite dangerous as anybody looking at my screen when I type can read my password.

I know that you can display it by right clicking on the password field and click "reveal password" (or equivalent), but I never click on this thing.
So, IMO, there is only two possibilities:

- there is a shortcut (to reveal password in password field) that I'm not aware of, and that I type by mistake before entering my password. In that case, what is this shortcut? is there any possibility to disable it?
- or this is done manually in a malicious intent, to read my password when I'm typing it (I'm working with hackers so this option is also to be considered)

Comment: I don't know how you worked out you're on Ubuntu 18.04.1; but I'd check what you're actually running.  A fully upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system will report itself as being [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) so if it's reporting 18.04.1 you may not have applied security packages since [early 2019](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/02/15/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-released/)

Comment: ```uname -a``` gives ```[...]  5.4.0-91-generic #102~18.04.1-Ubuntu [...]```. good point about missing security packages

Comment: That's your kernel detail, and doesn't tell you the OS & update level.  Try using `lsb_release -a` to show details (lsb=linux standard base; you won't have any modules installed/available but that doesn't matter)

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic